# Get Class Label in Faster -RCNN with gluoncv

Tags: python, python-3.x, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to count the number of vehicles in images using Faster-RCNN implementation in gluoncv as shown in [here](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/build/examples_detection/demo_ssd.html). I want to get the string label of the image. For example, in the following image, the string label would be 'bus'. How can I get it?

[An image of a bus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHcH2.jpg)

Following is my implementation.

```
import os
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from gluoncv import model_zoo, data, utils

vehiclesum1 = []

for filename in glob.glob('/home/xx/PythonCode/test/*.jpg'):
    x, orig_img = data.transforms.presets.rcnn.load_test(filename)    

    box_ids, scores, bboxes = net(x)
    ax = utils.viz.plot_bbox(orig_img, bboxes[0], scores[0], box_ids[0], class_names=net.classes)

    # I want to identify this label1
    vehiclesum1.append(label1.count('car') + label1.count('truck') + label1.count('motorcycle') + label1.count('bus'))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
# map class ID to classes
id2string = [i:name for i, name in enumerate(net.classes)]

# filter on score.
thresh = 0.8
top_classIDs = [c for c, s in zip(box_ids[0], scores[0]) if s > thresh]

# convert IDs to class names into "label1"
label1 = [id2string[c] for c in top_classIDs]
```